# Python lxml etree check if node exists

Tags: python, python-2.7, lxml

I have this XML:

```
<MasterPage>
    <NextPage>
        <prefix>
```

I want to check if the `prefix` node exists; I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
self.doc=etree.parse(xmlFile)
if hasattr(self.doc, 'MasterPage/NextPage/prefix'):
```

Comment: Your `xml` is not well-formed.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from lxml.html import fromstring
>>> import lxml.html as PARSER
>>> data = """<MasterPage>
...              <NextPage>
...                  <prefix>"""
>>> root = PARSER.fromstring(data) 
>>> node_list = []
>>> for ele in root.getiterator():
...     node_list.append(ele.tag)
... 
>>> if "prefix" in node_list:
...     print "True"
... 
True
>>> node_list
['masterpage', 'nextpage', 'prefix']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the find() or findall() function from etree library.

Comment: what does find() returns when there is no node please?